# IOT Application Enablement destination "ConfigurationAPI" 404: Not Found error

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

I created the IOT Application Enablement destination "ConfigurationAPI" as in [Help portal](https://help.sap.com/viewer/195126f4601945cba0886cbbcbf3d364/1903a/en-US/ecfc168953ea4fb0ad123f70cc399744.html).

I performed all the configurations until this step. The configuration I set is as follows
[image]

After checking the connection I am getting 404 not found error as

[image]

Any thoughts about this issue or any possible resolving steps?

Answer (score 1):

The "check connection" is not really checking the connection end to end. Please don't let this distract you and carry on with the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The subaccounts NEO and CF using for the configuration should be under the same global account.